# Errors using proxies with CURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, tcp, proxy

I'm using `CURL` on `localhost` using Xampp to connect to a website, But most of the times I get errors.

Here is the code:

```
//Website
$url = 'https://www.stubhub.com';

//Curl
$curl=curl_init();

//SSL
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\cacert.pem' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );

//Proxy
$proxies = array('71.6.46.151:443', '47.52.153.167:443');
$proxy = array_rand($proxies, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxies[$proxy]);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,__DIR__."/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
```

I get errors like:

1-

```
*   Trying 47.52.153.167...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 47.52.153.167 (47.52.153.167) port 443 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.stubhub.com:443
> CONNECT www.stubhub.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stubhub.com:443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 15:02:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 182
< Connection: close
< 
* The requested URL returned error: 400
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 47.52.153.167 left intact
The requested URL returned error: 400
```

2-

```
*   Trying 71.6.46.151...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 71.6.46.151 (71.6.46.151) port 443 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to stubhub.com:443
> CONNECT stubhub.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: stubhub.com:443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
> GET ?par=true HTTP/1.1
Host: stubhub.com:443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Referer: http://stubhub.com
Cookie: __gads=ID=54881b435fa43afa:T=1503588270:S=ALNI_MbVD2Ao8yOp5fAU1IUej6LT45ToIg; _br_uid_2=uid%3D6570057076657%3Av%3D12.0%3Ats%3D1503411310287%3Ahc%3D57; _ga=GA1.2.967466236.1503411311; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1503411309917r0.0876355868595391

* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 71.6.46.151 left intact
```

What is the reason for these errors?

Is there is something wrong with the proxies array (format) or the functions?

Should I use proxies with specific criteria?

Comment: Q: Is there error consistent (always works with one proxy, always fails with the other), or intermittant?  ALSO: Look [here](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587401/cannot-make-a-curl-request-through-a-proxy-in-php).  Be sure to double-check your nginx config on all proxies, too.

Comment: It looks like you don't want to be using the tunnel option with these proxies.  And the nature of these open proxies is that they may not be reliable. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL.html

Comment: @paulsm4, I'm using Xampp on my local device not a server

Comment: @paulsm4, I change the array of the proxies multiple times with about 3-5 proxies, I make requests to the homepage then to other links from that page, So each page may be with the same or another proxy

Comment: @drew010, but in this case my IP would be detected, The website is using a service that redirects to Recaptcha to prevent bots

Comment: The problem is the proxy you are using not your code. You can try to use with other clients and you will see the same problems.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Should I use proxies with specific criteria or from specific place?

Comment: Should I use proxy with the same port of Apache(443) or one supports https?

Comment: @Bon: there is no clear indicator like port number which will work. Some proxies like 47.52.153.167:443 will work with http:// URL's but not with https://, others work with both. You cannot assume that if you just take  proxies from some list on the internet that they work at all and even if they seem to work that they are not malicious.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, What if the website is `https` and I entered 'http' instead ? WOuld it work then?

Comment: Also is there is a trusted places/APIs for getting proxies for these purposes?

Comment: Silly Q: Why exactly do you need to use proxies in the first place?

Comment: @Bon: *"What if the website is https and I entered 'http' instead ? WOuld it work then?"* - this depends on the website. Some might work, others will redirect to https:// and then you face the same problem. -- *"Also is there is a trusted places/APIs for getting proxies for these purposes?"* - it is not even clear what the purpose is. But I very much doubt that you can get a curated and always up-to-date list of working non-malicious proxies for free. Somebody would have to do the work. And similar somebody must pay for the servers and bandwidth used by these proxies too.

Comment: @paulsm4, The website is using a service for blocking bots, scraping and attacks, So I have to use different headers